# Can't get nginx to load PHP on OSX

Tags: php, macos, nginx

So I'm trying to get nginx and php working on OSX.  I followed this guide:
https://www.sylvaindurand.org/setting-up-a-nginx-web-server-on-os-x/

But set up the root to point to Sites in my home folder and put two simple files in there:

index.htm

```
<body>
    <h1>Here I am!</h1>
    <p>NGINX is working.</p>
</body>
```

and

index.php

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo '<p>PHP is working!</p>'; ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

When I point a browser directly to the html file or configure the nginx.conf to load it first it works fine.  But I can't get it to load any php files, right now it just says "File not found."  I've looked around and found people with similar problems, but none of the solutions I've found fix mine.  I'm new to PHP so I'm flailing in the dark a bit.  Any ideas what I've done wrong?

Here's my nginx.conf:

```
user  Maddux staff;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root  /Users/Maddux/Sites/;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           /Users/Maddux/Sites/;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}
    include servers/*;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `location ~ \.php$` block is confusing as your set the `root` and them immediately override it.

If you want PHP-FPM to use the same document root as `nginx` in order to find your PHP scripts, the value for `SCRIPT_FILENAME` should be set to either:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

or:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
```

In your case, both values are identical.

Also, it is not necessary to put an identical `root` value into every `location` block, as `root` is inherited. It is usual to place a single `root` directive near the top of the `server` block, and only place `root` directives within `location` blocks where the value is different. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for more.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I've made your suggested fixes, however I'm still getting "File not found."  But this at least gives me a lot more to investigate.  I've got a lot to learn here.